# Not able to call selenium keyword written in python in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I have created one directory(ExternalKeyword) and inside directory created one CommonKeywords.py file, inside .py file written code below

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from robot.libraries.DateTime import datetime
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command
class BasePage():
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = SeleniumLibrary(run_on_failure='Nothing')
        self.builtin = BuiltIn()
        self.datetime = datetime
        self.set_browser_settings()
    def screenshot(self):
        self.session.capture_page_screenshot()
    def set_browser_settings(self, browser='gc', timeout=10, implicit_wait=10, speed=0.1, run_on_failure='screenshot',
                             screenshot_root_directory=None):
        self.browser = browser
        self.selenium_timeout = timeout
        self.implicit_wait = implicit_wait
        self.selenium_speed = speed
        self.run_on_failure = run_on_failure
    def input_text1(self, locator, text):
        for i in range(3):
            try:
                self.session.wait_until_element_is_visible(locator)
                self.session.input_text(locator, text)
                break

            except:
                if i in range(2):
                    self.builtin.sleep(2)
                else:
                    self.screenshot()
                    raise
```

Now I am trying to call input_text1 keyword in .robot file. But I can't able to call getting below error. Undefined keyword
Below is the code were calling input_text1 from .py file.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  ../ExternalKeywords/UserDefinedKeywords.py
Library  ../ExternalKeywords/CommonKeywords.py


*** Keywords ***
Lounch Browser
    [Arguments]   ${url}  ${Browser}
    Open Browser  ${url}  ${Browser}
    Maximize Browser Window
Login into application
    [Arguments]  ${UserName}  ${Password}
    input_text1   id=UserName    ${UserName}
    input_text    id=Password    ${Password}
    get_text      id=loginButton
    Click Button    id=loginButton
```

Can someone help me to resolve my issue. why I am not able to call python keyword in .robot file.

Comment: _"But I can't able to call getting below error."_ - you seem to have forgotten to post the error.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to write a keyword that works with the selenium library is to use the [get library instance](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance) keyword to get a reference to the instance of `SeleniumLibrary`, instead of directly instantiating the class.

Example:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class BasePage():
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")
```

When you do it like that, and assuming your test has imported the library and opened a browser, you are able to call the SeleniumLibrary keywords via `self.session` like you do elsewhere in your code:

```
def screenshot(self):
    self.session.capture_page_screenshot()
```